# find exact match with grep

Tags: r, text

I am attempting to take a fairly large dataframe of comments from a survey and use `grep` to identify comments that contain one of a list of keywords

```
index <- c(1:3)
comments <- c("My boss was good", "My bosses were great", "Goodness gracious I love my boss")
reviews <- as.data.frame(index,comments)

list = "good|leave|absense|physical|medical|sick"
```

What I want to do is create a new column in this dataframe which will contain only comments which contain an exact match of the strings from the 'list' vector.
So from the 'comments' field I want [1] since in contains "good" which is in the 'list' vector but not [3] because "goodness" is not an exact match to "good".

This is what I've come up with so far:

```
new_column <- reviews[grep(list,reviews$comments, fixed=TRUE), ]
```

When I run this, however, I get a new colunmn with 0 observations despite the fact that there are comments that contain words which I included in 'list'.

I know that there are similar posts to this in the past but I have still not been able to find a good solution.

Answer (score 1):

Use an alternation with word boundaries:

```r
regex <- "\\b(?:good|leave|absense|physical|medical|sick)\\b"
df <- reviews[grepl(regex, reviews$comments), ]
df


  index         comments
1     1 My boss was good
```

**Data:**

```
index <- c(1:3)
comments <- c("My boss was good", "My bosses were great", "Goodness gracious I love my boss")
reviews <- data.frame(index,comments)
```

Comment: This is bizarre. This code you gave me works. When I apply it to my test datasets, it works. When I apply it to the full dataset (56,000 rows) with up to 1,000 characters per line, it fails to work. 
When I say "fails" I mean it runs into the issue where it will return values like "goodness" when I only wanted "good".

Do you know if R ever had scaling problems or if too much text can cause this operation to break down?

Comment: @AlexN If the regex alternation have too many items in it, it could cause the regex engine to fail.  You should look into that.  If so, you might have to use an explicit look over terms, or possibly use a different regex library.